# Prove that $\exists c>0$ s.t $\sum_{n\geq x}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{c}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all $x \in [1, \infty)$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{c}{x}$

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$ Evidently,

$\displaystyle\bigg[\displaystyle\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg]{\lfloor x \rfloor}\leq x\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \displaystyle\bigg[\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg]{\lceil x \rceil} $.

This inequality arises since,

$\displaystyle\bigg[\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg]=\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Now, let $\lfloor x\rfloor=m$

$\displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty}\bigg[\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg]m$

$=\lim_{{m \to \infty},{r\to \infty}}\bigg[\frac{m}{(m+1)^2}+\frac{m}{(m+2)^2}+\frac{m}{(m+3)^2}+...+\frac{m}{(m+r)^2}+...\bigg]=$

$\lim_{{h \to 0},{r\to \infty}}h\bigg[\frac{1}{(1+h)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+2h)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+3h)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+rh)^2}+...\bigg]=\displaystyle\int_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=1$

We have, $\lceil x\rceil=m+1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty}\bigg[\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg](m+1)=\lim_{m \to \infty}\bigg[\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{j^2}\bigg]m$

Thereby, we conclude, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}x\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2}=1 $.

Therefore, from the definition of limit, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists G>0$ such that $\bigg|x\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2}-1\bigg|<\varepsilon$ $\forall x>G$. Choosing $\varepsilon =1$, we get $G=G_0$ such that $x\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2}<2$, for any $x> G_0$.

We set $\displaystyle c=\max\bigg\{2, \sup_{x\in [1,G_0]}x\sum_{n \geq x}\frac{1}{n^2} \bigg\}$

Is this procedure valid? Kindly verify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that the following happens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222626/prove-that-there-exists-a-constant-c0-such-that-the-following-happens)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2591225/42969

Comment: Since part of the question is a critique of the approach in the question, I don't see this as a duplicate of either question mentioned so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comments**

I had initially thought that, although $x$ is usually a real variable, $x$ was intended to be an integer. However, if $x$ is intended to take on any real value, one needs to be clear on exactly what is meant, since this is not a standard use for $\sum$. Here are two that come to mind at first:
$$
\sum_{n\ge x}\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=\lceil x\rceil}^\infty\frac1{n^2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n\ge x}\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+x)^2}
$$
That point aside, your approach of finding the limit and using that for all $x$ past a finite value, and then handling the initial finite range of $x$ separately, is quite valid.

---

**Slick Answer**

For $m\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{n^2}
&\le\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{\left(n-\frac12\right)\left(n+\frac12\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge m}\left(\frac1{n-\frac12}-\frac1{n+\frac12}\right)\\
&=\frac1{m-\frac12}\\[3pt]
&\le\frac2m
\end{align}
$$

---

**Less Slick Answer**

For $m\ge2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{n^2}
&\le\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{(n-1)n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge m}\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right)\\
&=\frac1{m-1}\\[3pt]
&\le\frac2m
\end{align}
$$
For $m=1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{n^2}
&\le1+\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{(n-1)n}\\
&=1+\sum_{n\ge 2}\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right)\\
&=2\\[6pt]
&=\frac2m
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The notation seems unambiguous to me: $n$ ranges over all integers that are $\ge x$.

Comment: That is the first of the two possibilities I listed, but then why allow $x$ to be real other than to make the bound a bit more difficult to compute? The second interpretation, which is similar to that used to extend [Harmonic Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506068) continuously to all real (or complex) limits, at least gives a reason for considering real limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off starting with an integral from the start:
$$\frac 1{n^2} \le \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac 1{t^2} \, dt.$$
For any <s>integer $k$</s> [edited to address complaint] integer $k \ge 2$ you have
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} \le \int_{k-1}^\infty \frac 1{t^2} \, dt = \frac 1{k-1}$$

From here it is not too difficult.

Comment: What constant can you get for $k\ge1$ for $\frac1{k-1}\le\frac{c}{k}$?

Comment: Don't be dense. If $k = 1$ the sum is bounded. If $k \ge 2$ then $$\sum_{n=k} \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac 1{k-1} = \frac 1k \frac{k}{k-1} \le \frac 2k.$$

Comment: No need for name calling. I am simply pointing out that $\frac1{k-1}$ does not answer the question as it stands. For $k\ge2$, a constant of $2$ works, but one needs to handle $k=1$ separately.

Comment: Of course it didn't answer the question. Hence the last sentence "From here it is not too difficult".

Comment: I already upvoted, but I appreciate the edit.

Comment: It is a better idea. Anyways, is my proof correct? A review of what I have done would be really helpful :)